# Returning a value after checking which button is checked and grabbing a value from a field

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I'm having trouble with an assignment. I need to grab the user input from 2 text fields and either add, substract, multiply, or divide them, then display the answer. I'm also not sure on how to display the answer, I've been trying to get it to show up on the paragraph but I can't seem to get it to work. Thanks in advance!

JavaScript

```
<script>
    var number=new Object();
    number.Num1="";
    number.Num2="";
            function processData(Num1,Num2) {

        // get all the fields' values
        number.Num1 = document.getElementById(Num1).value;
        number.Num2 = document.getElementById(Num2).value;

        //Check which radio button is checked
         if (document.getElementById('Add').checked) 

         //Shoot out answer
return Num1+Num2;
        //Write answer
document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML=processData(Num1,Num2)

            }
</script>
```

HTML form

```
<table><tr>
<td height="600" align="center"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <p>Input the two numbers that you wish to calculate!</p>
  <p>
    <label>First Number!
      <input type="text" name="Num1" id="Num1" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Second Number!
      <input type="text" name="Num2" id="Num2" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Please choose what you wish to do with the numbers!</p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Add" value="Add" id="Add" />
      Add</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Multiply" value="Multiply" id="Multiply" />
      Multiply</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Substract" value="Substract" id="Substract" />
      Substract</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Divide" value="Divide" id="Divide" />
      Divide</label>
  </p>
  <p>Click Submit to get your answer!</p>
  <p>
    <label>Click me!
       <input type="submit" name="Button" id="Button" value="Submit" onclick="processData('Num1','Num2')" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Your answer is : </p> <p id="Answer"> </p><br />

</form></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use same name for radio button group and get the value

Comment: not any research done.

Answer (score 0):

First provide your radio buttons same name, So It denotes to a group which make sure that only one radio button will be checked. lets say it to 'Operation' like

```
<p>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Operation" value="Add" id="Add" />
  Add</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Operation" value="Multiply" id="Multiply" />
  Multiply</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Operation" value="Substract" id="Substract" />
  Substract</label>
<br />
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="Operation" value="Divide" id="Divide" />
  Divide</label>
</p>
```

Now change your js code to

```
var number=new Object();
number.Num1= 0;
number.Num2= 0;

function processData(Num1,Num2) {

    // get all the fields' values
    // parse your fields value to number
    number.Num1 = Number(document.getElementById(Num1).value);
    number.Num2 = Number(document.getElementById(Num2).value);

    // a variable to hold the answer
    var answer = 0; 

    //Check which radio button is checked
    if (document.getElementById('Add').checked) {
        answer = number.Num1 + number.Num2;
    } else if (document.getElementById('Multiply').checked) {
        answer = number.Num1 * number.Num2;
    } else if (document.getElementById('Subtract').checked) {
        answer = number.Num1 - number.Num2;
    } else if (document.getElementById('Divide').checked) {
        // if number.Num2 =0 then it will product Divide by Zero error
        // So We are checking if number.Num2 === 0 then display 0 else perform the operation.

        answer = number.Num2 === 0 ? 0 : (number.Num1 / number.Num2);

        // You can also change this ternary operation to if..else condition like
        /*
         if(number.Num2 !== 0){
            answer = number.Num1 / number.Num2;
         }
        */

    }

    document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = answer;

    return false;
 }
```

You need to make change in your button markup to prevent form submittion, you can change it to (change type to button so It not submit the form)

```
<input type="button" name="Button" id="Button" value="Submit" onclick="processData('Num1','Num2')" />
```

or (place return false in end to js function and change onclick to `onclick="return processData('Num1','Num2')"` so It does not submit the form.

```
<input type="submit" name="Button" id="Button" value="Submit" onclick="return processData('Num1','Num2')" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Everything seems to be working and it looks much cleaner, except I still can't display the answer on the form. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2992279, `document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = answer;` this statement will show the answer in `Answer` p tag

Comment: @user2992279, Answer is updated, You need to either change type="submit" to type="button" or return false from function and call function with return statement in onclick.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the following code:

```
 <script>
    var number = new Object();
    Num1 = "";
    Num2 = "";
    function processData(Num1, Num2) {
      //debugger;
        // get all the fields' values
        Num1 = document.getElementById('Num1').value;
        Num2 = document.getElementById('Num2').value;
        if (Num1 == null || Num1 == "" || Num1 == undefined) {
            Num1 = 0;
        }
        if (Num2 == null || Num2 == ""|| Num2==undefined) {
            Num2 = 0;
        }
        var answer=0;
        //Check which radio button is checked
        if (document.getElementById('Add').checked) {
            //Shoot out answer
            answer = Number(Num1) + Number(Num2);
        }
        if (document.getElementById('Multiply').checked) {
            //Shoot out answer
            answer = Number(Num1) * Number(Num2);
        }
        if (document.getElementById('Substract').checked) {
            //Shoot out answer
            answer = Number(Num1) - Number(Num2);
        }
        if (document.getElementById('Divide').checked) {
            //Shoot out answer
            answer = Number(Num1) /Number (Num2);
        }


        //Write answer
        document.getElementById("Answer").innerHTML = answer;

    }
   </script>
```

And you have to change your input type to button instead of submit button
by the following code:

```
<input type="button" name="Button" id="Button" value="Submit"         
onclick="processData('Num1','Num2')" />
```